# Can I get a top x% of pages accounts for y% of views kind of report with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

For example we know that for YouTube 1% of videos generates the 99% of the views.

Can I extract a similar data from Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is a way to get summarized data like that from Analytics, but you can always view the dashboard stats:

```
Dashboard > Content > Site Content > All Pages
```

This will show you the total # of Pageviews at the top and then a breakdown of specific page view information at the bottom. You can then just see which pages account for what % of traffic.

Edited for Cedivad:
If it's a lot of data you might need to access the info directly using the Analytics API. Here's the documentation on how to query info on [site content by pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataCommonQueries#content).

Comment: i cannot do that with a 3 million pages website :)

Comment: With that many pages, you might want to try accessing the data directly through the API. Here's the documentation on [how to access your site content](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataCommonQueries#content) by pageview.

Comment: @cedivad with that volume you might want to consider acquiring Google Analytics Premium Edition. That will enable you to see a full report.

Comment: thank you eduardocereto, i just find an "exploit" that allows me to export 10000 results per page without even bothering using the api. it works fine! it's like editing the url and inserting 10000 instead of 100 in the "per page" url variable. :)

Comment: and anyway i don't have a $150,000 Annual Flat Fee to pay for this :P